# How to print a Pentomino rectangle using c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, terminal

I have a 6x10 array which defines the shape that I should print . For example

```
{'a','b','b','b','c','c','c','d','e','e'},
{'a','b','f','f','f','c','d','d','d','e'},
{'a','b','f','f','g','c','h','d','e','e'},
{'a','i','i','g','g','h','h','h','j','j'},
{'a','i','g','g','k','h','j','j','j','l'}, 
{'i','i','k','k','k','k','l','l','l','l'}
```

is same as the this picture :

[image]

I should use these characters :
  [image]

My code is this :

```
void PrintSolution()
{
    for (i=0; i<6 ; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<10 ; j++)
        {
            char a=board[i][j], b=board[i][j+1], c=board[i+1][j+1], d=board[i+1][j];

            if (a==b==c==d)
                cout<<(char)32;

            if (a==d && b==c && a!=c)
                cout<<(char)179;


            if (b==c && a!=b && a!=d && c!=d)
                cout<<(char)180;

            if (a==b==c && d!=a)
                cout<<(char)191;

            if (a==c==d && b!=a)
                cout<<(char)192;

            if (c==d && a!=b && a!=d && b!=c)
                cout<<(char)193;

            if (a==b && a!=c && a!=d && d!=c)
                cout<<(char)194;

            if (a==d && a!=c && a!=b && b!=c)
                cout<<(char)195;

            if (a==b && c==d && a!=c)
                cout<<(char)196;

            if (a!=b && b!=c && a!=d && d!=c)
                cout<<(char)197;

            if (b==c==d && a!=b)
                cout<<(char)217;

            if (a==b==d && a!=c)
                cout<<(char)218;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

It looks for every four elements in the matrix and accordingly prints the proper characters but it prints a mess! I don't know whether I should change the algorithm or add some details to the code .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Further, questions like yours must come with a [mcve], i.e. you are supposed to first reduce you problem to the core. Without that, your question is considered off-topic.

Comment: Please note how many chars are used in the reference picture (which shouldn't be an image, but a copy-pasted text) to draw the pentominoes. You should also check the indeces before accessing arrays out of bounds.

Comment: `if (a==b==c==d)` Hmm.. did you get a warning for this?

Comment: @Bob__ I don't know how to find number of characters . It's just a picture without further details .

Comment: @4386427 No , I didn't get a message for that .

Comment: @S.H.W Then turn up the warning level, e.g. for gcc do "gcc -Wall program.c". That line is not doing what you think.

Comment: @4386427 Okay , thanks . Can you help me for printing that pattern please ? I really have no idea .

Comment: @S.H.W First of all you need to add special handling of the borders.

Comment: @4386427 Do you mean printing a rectangle around the shape ?

Comment: just in case you didn't get the point the others made `a==b==c` is not what you want. You need to write `a==b && b==c` explicitly. Let's imagine a,b and c being all 2 then `a==b==c` would be `2==2==2` which is `(2==2)==2` which is `(true)==2` whhich is `1==2` which is `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add special code for handling the border. Your current code ignores the border for the first row and worse, you access outside the array when `i` is 5 and `j` is 9. For instance here: `c=board[i+1][j+1]`.

Further, I'll suggest that you use `if-else` to make the code more clear, i.e. so that it is obvious that you only print one char in each loop. Then later you can optimize it.

The code below is not a full solution - it's some code to give you a better start.

```
void PrintSolution()
{
    for (int i=0; i<6 ; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<10 ; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    // Special case, i.e. first row, first column

                    // Here the output is: ┌
                }
                else if (j == 9)
                {
                    // Special case, i.e. first row, last column

                    // Here the output is one of: ┬ or ─
                    if (board[i][j-1] == board[i][j])
                    {
                        // Here the output is: ─
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Here the output is: ┬
                    }

                    // And an extra char for last column
                    // Here the output is: ┐
                }
                else
                {
                    // Special case, i.e. first row

                    // Here the output is one of: ┬ or ─
                    if (board[i][j-1] == board[i][j])
                    {
                        // Here the output is: ─
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Here the output is: ┬
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (i == 5)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    // Special case, i.e. last row, first column
                }
                else if (j == 9)
                {
                    // Special case, i.e. last row, last column
                }
                else
                {
                    // Special case, i.e. last row
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    // Special case, i.e. first column
                }
                else if (j == 9)
                {
                    // Special case, i.e. last column
                }
                else
                {
                    // Normal case
                }
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

As you can see, you'll end up with 9 different cases to consider.

Comment: Thanks but my main problem is handling the normal case . I don't whether my algorithm works or not .

Comment: @S.H.W I've completed the first row for you. That should give you an idea for the rest.

Comment: this seems unnecessarily verbose. The only information necessary to decide which character to print is the 4 characters around the border. Sure, there's a border on the outside, but the border can easily be handled without special-casing it by assigning it some constant that's not present within the border.

Comment: @PeterT As I write before the code this is on purpose made so that each case is handled by its own `if-else` block. And that the code can be optimized later. The idea is to "keep each case simple" so that OP can figure out the solution. And - yes - for all chars "in the middle" you only need to look at 4 array values.

Comment: @4386427 Thanks a lot .